# Azure DevOps: Copy chart configuration of saved query

Tags: azure-devops, tfs

I have set up a query in Azure DevOps, which I use to track the progress of an upcoming software release.

I have furthermore set up some chart configuration in the queries' chart editor. Works fine.

Now I want to use the same chart visualisation for the next release. So I copied the query configuration, gave it a new name. I expected it to not only copy the query details, but also the chart configuration attached to it. But and all the charts are gone. So I assume I'd have to re-setup the chart configuration every time?

Does anyone know a way to make sure that with copying a query, it will also copy and presever the associated chart configuration?